# Why is this considered constant?

Tags: c++, utf-8

I have a stack of UTF8 characters:

```
stack<wchar_t> tokenStack;
```

i try to add to it like this:

```
void doLeftParen() { tokenStack.push( L"(" ) }
```

but the compiler doesn't like it:

$ g++ PropositionalLogic.cpp -o PropositionalLogic

> PropositionalLogic.cpp:27:39: error: reference to type 'const value_type'
>         (aka 'const wchar_t') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'const wchar_t [2]'
>   void doLeftParen() { tokenStack.push( L"(" ) }

I tried searching for the error, but came up empty.  I'm not really sure what else i should be searching for.  I've also tried just adding a regular ASCII character, but same error.  How can i add characters to this stack?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon

Comment: The problem is not that it's constant, it's that `L"("` is an array of two characters instead of being a single character. `L'('` (single quotes) is probably what you want to use.

Comment: Note that this is not utf8, but probably utf16

Comment: I think you mean "Unicode characters" - UTF-8 is a transfer encoding, and normally accessed via a `char*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to push a string not a char, changing the double quotes to single quotes will make it work, also you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the push function

```
void doLeftParen() { tokenStack.push( L'(' ); }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost right:

From [lex.ccon](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#nt:escape-sequence)

> A character literal that begins with the letter `L`, such as `L'z'`,
>   is a *wide-character* literal.

Characters with prefix `L` is **not** a *UTF8 character literal*.

The compile error in your code is `L"("` (w/ double-quotes) is a *multicharater literal* but the code expects it to be a stack of *wide character literal*s.

Change it to single-quotes:

```
L'(' // now a wide-char literal
```